# Filtering VCF files with bcftools

Tags: annotations, bcftools, vcftools

From an annotated vcf file generated with annovar, I try to extract the variants that are exonic, splicing, that does not lead to synonymous mutation and have gnomad allele frequency lower than 0.01. I want to save these variants in a txt file. In order to do that I use this command line:

```
bcftools query -f '%CHROM\t%POS\t%ID\t%REF\t%ALT\t%INFO/Func.refGene\t%INFO/Gene.refGene\t%INFO/GeneDetail.refGene\t%INFO/ExonicFunc.refGene\t%INFO/AAChange.refGene\t%INFO/gnomad40_genome_AF\n' -i '(INFO/Func.refGene="exonic" || INFO/Func.refGene="exonic;splicing" || INFO/Func.refGene="splicing") && INFO/ExonicFunc.refGene!="synonymous" && INFO/gnomad40_genome_AF<0.01' input.vcf > ouput.txt
```

I get this Error: cannot use arithmetic operators to compare strings and numbers

Does anyone now how I can change my command line in order to extract variants with gnomad allele frequency lower than 0.01.

Thank you in advance!